# Is package-lock.json guaranteeing a specific version in npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, malware

This is regarding supply chain attacks.

Is it possible for the creator of an npm package to change published packages in retrospect?

For example, `pkg@1.0.0` is trusted right now, and pinned in my `package-lock.json`. Now, can the publisher change `pkg@1.0.0` on npmjs.com, so when I run `npm i` a malicious version gets installed?

If so, how do I prevent this?

I tried googling and haven't found any info about this.

Comment: you could always make your own checksum for a version you trust. I don't think `npm` will update your local for what it thinks is the same version, even if it's changed surreptitiously at the npm server.